# zclip embedded zeroclipboardmovie container position not aligning with button

Tags: javascript, php, css, zeroclipboard, zclip

I'm having trouble aligning the clickable area for the zclip button with the actual button.

This page shows the button with the problem:
http://www.dropshiplounge.com/test-page/

This is the code I'm using for the zclip:

```
<form action="" method="post">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                            jQuery('button#copy_mario').zclip({
                                path:'<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                                copy: ''
                            });
                        })
                    </script>

<button id="copy_mario" type="button"><img src=""></button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the code didn't post. The website has the problem button, I hope that's enough.  I'm not experienced with this sort of stuff. Thanks!

Comment: you can do  clip reposition check this ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842977/zclip-swf-does-not-align-with-button-position-if-button-position-changes

Comment: I tried
`<form action="" method="post">
                 <script type="text/javascript">
a(window).bind("load resize", function(){
        d.reposition()
      })
$(window).trigger('reload');
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                            jQuery('button#copy_m').zclip({
                                path:'<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                                copy: ''
                            });
                        })
                    </script>

<button id="copy_m" type="button"><img src=""></button>`

Comment: But I know I'm doing it wrong. How can I impliment that?